# How to build a stream of wifi signal with flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, stream

I want to create a stream that changes as the WIFI signal changes but my code only give 1 value and wont change. I'm using WIFI FLUTTER package to get the WIFI signal [WIFI FLUTTER](https://github.com/alternadom/WiFiFlutter)

Here my function to scan a WIFI signal

```
 Future<int> getWifiSignals() async {

   _htResultNetwork = await loadWifiList();

   return _htResultNetwork[0].level;

}
```

Then i build it using Stream Builder

```
  StreamBuilder(
            stream: Stream.fromFuture(getWifiSignals()),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
          },)
```

but the signal doesn't change I'm new to flutter btw.

Comment: `Stream.fromFuture` will only ever fire one event, when the future completes. Unless your plugin supports a event based stream, you won't have much choice but to poll it. Use `Timer.periodic` to trigger a periodic call to `loadWifiList` and add each result to the stream.

Comment: can you give simple code snippet on how to use stream.peridic with future online example only using int